# value is not returned from database

Tags: javascript, database

I'm trying to fetch a **value from database** like this

```
var batsmanId = getBatsmanid(localStorage.getItem('batsmanOne'));
```

Here is the method definition:

```
function getBatsmanid(name){
 var id;
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM player where player_name = ?',[name], function(tx, results) {
       id = results.rows.item(0).player_id;
       console.log('Batsman ID: '+id);
      });
     });        
     return id;
}
```

While executing, **the method is not returning `id` to the variable `batsmanId`**, whereas the value is shown in console.

My feel is the *database operation is taking time to execute*.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Maybe you forgot semi colon?

Comment: @B.K. May I know the right place to drop the `;`.  But there is no error in console.

Comment: Car to share your executeSql function?

Might be missing a return statement from there, stick a console message right a the start and see if the callback is called. Check that executeSql is a) sending the query. b) something is being returned.

Comment: @SOliver Thanks.  Give me a few minute, I will check and update you.

Comment: @user1671639: I believe that you haven't understood asynchronous behaviour yet, at least in node.js. Think of any function that accepts a callback as an AJAX request, that could make it easier for you (I guess you're accustomed to AJAX since you work with jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feeling is correct.

In Javascript you cannot (shouldn't) "wait" for something to happen, and the model used is the opposite and more like "call me when you're done".

The function passed to `executeSQL` that is extracting the data will be called at a later time, and you should rework your interface around this approach (that is instead of just setting the variable `id` do the rest of the processing needed with that `id` once it arrives).

Comment: Isn't tx.executeSql taking a callback as a parameter?

Comment: @SOliver: Yes. and s/he should be using that to do the processing. Instead the code shown is just using the callback to set the result.